# How to create a function call in javascript with xhtml?

Tags: javascript, xhtml-1.1

Here is the code that i have so far I am having trouble getting the code to execute the function and properly output the data from the function to the "Total BMI" text box I have been searching for hours on this trying to figure it out. this is a class assignment I am having trouble with it because I am not understanding the syntax used in javascript to do everything that I need done. My teacher is literally of no help as this is our second assignment and has never had a lecture on how to even begin writing code in Javascript. Thanks for any help that anyone may provide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>BMI Calculator</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="BMI.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function calcBMI(Height, Weight) {
     var h = parseInt(height);s
     var w = parseInt(Wieght);
     var TotalBMI = w * 703 / (h * h);
     document.write ("Your BMI is: " + TotalBMI)  
}

/* ]]> */
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>BMI Calculator</h2>
<form action="" name="BMI">
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Height :(in)</td><td><input type="text" name="Height" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Weight :(lbs)</td><td><input type="text" name="Weight" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type = "button" value = "Calculate" onclick = "calcBMI('Height', 'Weight')"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Total BMI:</td><td><input type="text" name="TotalBMI" value="" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Strict//EN"` is not real public identifier. You might want to check the spec.

Comment: Having trouble in executing your javascript function. is because of line: **`var h = parseInt(height);s`** why there is `s` after `;`? is it a typo? also you're passing parameters to function as **`(Height, Weight)`** and accessing them as: **`height`**, **`Wieght`**. That is Really Bad.

Comment: What *specific* problem are you having? Have you looked at your browser's JavaScript console? Are there any errors?

Comment: I will look into this I am just using that from the code for the first assignment we had.

Comment: You can't parse the string 'Height' into an int.

Comment: @VedantTerkar yes it was a typo.

Comment: Also you aren't using the same variables in your function as the the parameters. (Height != height, Wieght != Weight)

Comment: @Quentin I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined in the javascript console in my browser. I didn't even know i had that in my browser.

Comment: @MattR can you expand on your answer I am not sure I understand I am trying to pass the value of what I input into the text boxes as a parameter into the function what am I doing wrong. I truly have no idea.

Comment: Is that a requirement of the assignment?  Passing the values as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets look at this:

```
onclick = "calcBMI('Height', 'Weight')"
```

Your passing strings here, in which can't convert to be an integer (at least not the type your expecting). It appears you want to get the values of your elements with the names `Height` and `Width`. Well this is a good use of `id`'s other than `name`'s.

```
<tr><td>Height :(in)</td><td><input type="text" id="Height" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Weight :(lbs)</td><td><input type="text" id="Weight" value="" /></td></tr>
...
<tr><td>Total BMI:</td><td><input type="text" id="TotalBMI" value="" /></td></tr>
```

Now don't need any parameters for the `calcBMI()` functions because we can get them directly like so:

```
document.getElementById("Height").value;
```

So here are the changes to your function:

```
function calcBMI() {
    var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("Height").value);
    var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("Weight").value);
    var TotalBMI = w * 703 / (h * h);
    document.getElementById("TotalBMI").value = "Your BMI is: " + TotalBMI;  
}
```

Note I changed the `document.write()` to `.innerHTML`. Because running `document.write()` after the page loads rewrites the DOM.

Also note that submitting the `<form>` will refresh your page. It does not appear you really need the `<form>`, so I recommend just removing it. Either that or prevent the default *page refresh* behavior.

Comment: I like how our thought process / teaching style is exactly the same, haha. "First, let's look at this." "Here," (I know you wrote your answer without seeing mine.)

Comment: @AndrewCheong Haha! Yeah I know :)

Comment: Thank you both very much I was getting another error on line 14 of the code in console. so I looked at what it was referencing which was TotalBMI I then realized that I needed to set an id for that rather than a name.

Comment: @Phibermatrix - Don't be discouraged by the downvotes here; do come back. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
onclick = "calcBMI('Height', 'Weight')"
```

you're passing the strings `'Height'` and `'Weight'`, although you mean to pass the values of the related fields. Forms don't work that way, so instead you should get rid of the parameters altogether,

```
onclick = "calcBMI()"
```

and in the function, use DOM traversal to get the values you need. First, add some `id` attributes to the fields you're interested in, *e.g.*

```
<tr><td>Height :(in)</td><td><input type="text" name="Height" value="" id="height" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Weight :(lbs)</td><td><input type="text" name="Weight" value="" id="width" /></td></tr>
```

then get their value like so:

```
function calcBMI() {
     var h = parseInt(document.getElementById('height').value);
     var w = parseInt(document.getElementById('weight').value);
     var TotalBMI = w * 703 / (h * h);
     document.write ("Your BMI is: " + TotalBMI)  
}
```

Comment: Note to others: Obviously, there are better ways, and jQuery makes this trivial, but presumably the goal here is for OP to learn Javascript, so I'm just trying to bring light to his or her basic errors, and guide him or her to the next step.

Comment: so with javascript I don't have to define my function prototype with the variables I will be passing to it?

Comment: That _would_ seem like good design if you come from, say, a C++ background. It makes organizational sense to say, "The form _sends_ its values to this Javascript function." However, the problem is that the form doesn't really "know" anything about itself—typically, an `<input type="submit">` triggers _browser_ functionality that sends form data for HTTP POST. Forms weren't designed to "submit" to Javascript functions. So think of Javascript here, almost like a hack (though it's not). From that perspective, think of your whole HTML document as a "global" variable / environment; so you can do

Comment: without parameters and simply access the "global variable" `document` right from within your function. Again, I agree that that feels wrong, from a more traditional design perspective. If you really want, you _can_ pass variables, like this: `onclick = "calcBMI(document.getElementById('height').value, document.getElementById('weight').value)"`, but see, either way, you're accessing the global DOM structure (the document). If this is all over your head right now, truly, don't worry about it—just accept it for what it is and later it'll become much clearer.

Comment: Yeah I'm in advanced c++ and this class is going to be the death of me. The teacher is a very knowledgeable person but he doesn't teach  so everything I'm doing in this code I have looked up online and pieced together I feel like I'm not coding just playing a game of jumble trying to get the pieces in the right spot to make it workAnd he wants everything in a table and wants us to use css which don't get me wrong is a great thing I'm sure but I don't even know how to write this without css much less with it.

Comment: I do know that the css doesn't do anything but formatting text but if I didn't use a css file where would I write the formatting at?

Comment: please don't answer that question I'm just going to get confused I will fight that battle when i get to it

Comment: Haha, I'll answer you only because I have good news. Whereas HTML and JS are closely "tied" (from a learning perspective), _e.g._ you have to set the HTML `id` attributes right to access the fields from Javascript, and HTML and CSS are "tied" as well, CSS and JS are totally independent, so you shouldn't run into headaches as if your CSS might break JS or vice versa. You can think of the CSS portion as completely unrelated to JS; even simply ignore your JS while you do CSS.

Comment: OMG thats the best news I have had in so long!!! is there any recommended reading you all would send my way for me to actually understand what the hell I need to know. or to start getting my feet beneath me on this.

Comment: Here's how you should start. In the `<head></head>` section, add this: `<style>#weight { border: 5px solid blue; color: red; }</style>` and you should see something happen to your `id="weight"` field. Since you already have a programming background, this simple example should get you started, and you'll intuitively figure out the rest. In my example, the `#` sign refers to "Apply this to whatever element has the following `id`."

Comment: Now, the thing about `id` is, they have to be unique throughout your document, else your JS _and_ CSS could break. So, what if you wanted to apply a style to both your `height` and `weight` elements? I guess you _could_ do `<style>#weight { border: 5px solid blue; color: red; } #height { border: 5px solid blue; color: red; }</style>` but see how you have to duplicate code? The solution is to use **classes**. Think of classes as tags. You can tag both your elements the same thing, like so: `<input type="text" name="Height" value="" id="height" class="foobar" />` and

Comment: `<input type="text" name="Weight" value="" id="width" class="foobar" />`, and the CSS _specifier_ for classes is `.`, as opposed to `#`. So now you can just write your CSS _once_, like this: `<style>.foobar { border: 5px solid blue; color: red; }</style>`, and there you have it. I don't think you'll need to know more than what I've explained here, but to learn about even more advanced _selectors_, try [this link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/). To find out all the ways you can style things, try [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference).

Comment: Ignore all this until you get to it. Once you _try_ what I'm saying, it'll make perfect sense.

Comment: so id is basically a variable name

Comment: Sure, you can think of it that way. After all, the official word for "variable name" in C++ is... _identifier_ ;-)

Comment: Not a problem. Good luck.